# Ordered semaphore.aquire() in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, semaphore

I have multiple `multiprocessing.Process()` acquiring and releasing:

```
s = Semaphore(5)
```

Are the `s.acquire()` calls guaranteed to be fulfilled in sequence?

If not, what can I use instead so that the first requesting process gets access to the resource first?

Comment: What does "fulfilled in sequence" mean when the requests can be concurrent? How do you define the "first requesting process"?

Comment: I have 5 "resource" - And about 200 waiting processes that want to use them. "First requesting" I define on a time basis. Lets say this all takes 6 hour to complete, will the thread that attempts to acquire the resource at hour 1 be given the resource before the thread requesting one at hour 2, if one resource becomes free at hour 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`threading.Semaphore.acquire` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore.acquire) :

> If the internal counter is larger than zero on entry, decrement it by one and return True immediately.
> If the internal counter is zero on entry, block until awoken by a call to release(). Once awoken (and the counter is greater than 0), decrement the counter by 1 and return True. Exactly one thread will be awoken by each call to release(). **The order in which threads are awoken should not be relied on.**

(emphasis mine)

In other words, while you semaphore has not reached zero, calls will immediately succeed. Then, all calls will block, until one `release` is called. At this point, any thread could return from its `acquire`.

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :

```py
import threading

NB_TOTAL = 20
NB_SHARED = 5

sem = threading.Semaphore(5)


def acquire_semaphore_then_do_something(thread_number: int):
    sem.acquire()
    do_something(thread_number)
    sem.release()


def do_something(number: int):
    print(number)


# create the threads
threads = [threading.Thread(target=acquire_semaphore_then_do_something, args=(thread_number,))
           for thread_number in range(NB_TOTAL)]
# start them all
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
# wait for all of them to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

If you **REALLY** need threads to run **EXACTLY** in the order they were created, I recommend to handle things differently :

```py
import threading

NB_TOTAL = 20
NB_SHARED = 5

THREAD_LOCKS = [threading.Lock() for _ in range(NB_TOTAL)]
LOCKS_LOCK = threading.Lock()  # lock for the locks management
NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX = NB_SHARED


def acquire_sequentially_then_do_something(thread_number: int):
    # try to acquire the dedicated lock
    THREAD_LOCKS[thread_number].acquire()  # blocking
    # dedicated lock acquired, proceeding
    do_something(thread_number)
    # now it has finished its work, it can unlock the next thread
    global NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX
    if NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX < NB_TOTAL:
        with LOCKS_LOCK:
            THREAD_LOCKS[NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX].release()
            NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX += 1


def do_something(number: int):
    print(number)


# lock all the locks, except the NB_SHARED first : indexes from 0 to NB_SHARED-1
for number, lock in enumerate(THREAD_LOCKS):
    if number >= NB_SHARED:
        assert lock.acquire(blocking=False)
# create the threads
threads = [threading.Thread(target=acquire_sequentially_then_do_something, args=(thread_number,))
           for thread_number in range(NB_TOTAL)]
# start them all
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
# wait for all of them to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

correctly prints

```
0
1
2
[...]
17
18
19
```

The idea is that the `NEXT_UNLOCK_INDEX` will increase 1 by 1, each time unlocking the specific lock so that the corresponding thread can finally lock it and proceed. It ensures that the threads abide to the "first come, first serve" principle.